# WPF: exceptions in hyperlink event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, datagrid, hyperlink

I have a WPF DataGrid with a hyperlink column:

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding DocName}">
  <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>`
     <Style>
        <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DocLink_Click" />
     </Style>
  </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

The content of the column is not a URL; it is the name of a document that I need to download from a URL that is different from what the column displays.

It all works fine except for one thing: In some cases I need to display a `MessageBox` before downloading. Doing this results in a `System.IO.IOException`, which complains that the resource (the document name that was clicked) cannot be found. This dummy event handler will throw the exception every time:

```
private void DocLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Crash now!");
}
```

What can I do to prevent this?

**Edit**

As suggested, I tried this in a toy app, and it worked there. After experimentation, it turns out that this happens only if the event occurs in a navigable `Page` (not a `Window`). So now we have this:

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   StartupUri="NavWin.xaml">
</Application>
```

NavWin.xaml:

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.Container"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="NavTest" 
  Source="MainPage.xaml">
</NavigationWindow>
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainPage"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
  Title="MainPage" Height="350" Width="525">

  <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name">
           <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
              <Style>
                 <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="ItemLink_Click" />
              </Style>
           </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : Page
{
  ... 
  private void ItemLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Crash");
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try this outside of your application? I don't think this will fail in that case, I guess the problem is not in the code you provide

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - I've edited the question to show what I found.